# ssd_resnet50 model stuck when loading IR to the plugin

Tags: python, object-detection-api, openvino

I'm trying to run `SSD ResNet50 FPN COCO` (`ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03`) model on NCS2 using MYRIAD, Python API but it stucks when loading IR to the plugin with the following error.

```
E: [xLink] [     80143] handleIncomingEvent:240 handleIncomingEvent() Read failed -4

E: [xLink] [     80143] dispatcherEventReceive:308  dispatcherEventReceive() Read failed -4 | event 0x7f35137fde80 USB_WRITE_REQ

E: [xLink] [     80143] eventReader:256 eventReader stopped
E: [xLink] [     80144] dispatcherEventSend:908 Write failed event -4

E: [watchdog] [     81144] sendPingMessage:164  Failed send ping message: X_LINK_ERROR
E: [watchdog] [     82144] sendPingMessage:164  Failed send ping message: X_LINK_ERROR
E: [watchdog] [     83144] sendPingMessage:164  Failed send ping message: X_LINK_ERROR
E: [watchdog] [     84145] sendPingMessage:164  Failed send ping message: X_LINK_ERROR
```

...

The `Failed send ping message: X_LINK_ERROR` keeps showing until I pressed ctrl+C to kill the script. I noticed the `USB_WRITE_REQ` in the error so I thought it has something to do with USB3 port but when I tried a lighter model `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco`, it worked like a charm.

This is the script to generate IR (IR generated successfully)

```
python mo_tf.py --input_model ~/workspace/pi/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03/frozen_inference_graph.pb --output_dir ~/workspace/pi/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03/openvino_model/FP16 --tensorflow_use_custom_operations_config ~/intel/computer_vision_sdk/deployment_tools/model_optimizer/extensions/front/tf/ssd_v2_support.json --tensorflow_object_detection_api_pipeline_config ~/workspace/pi/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03/pipeline.config --data_type FP16
```

This is the script I used to test

```
python test.py -m ~/workspace/pi/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03/openvino_model/FP16/frozen_inference_graph.xml -i ~/workspace/object-detection/test_images/image.jpg -d MYRIAD
```

Here's the snippet of Python script

```
plugin = IEPlugin(device=args.device, plugin_dirs=args.plugin_dir)
if args.cpu_extension and 'CPU' in args.device:
    plugin.add_cpu_extension(args.cpu_extension)
# Read IR
log.info("Reading IR...")
net = IENetwork(model=model_xml, weights=model_bin)

if plugin.device == "CPU":
    supported_layers = plugin.get_supported_layers(net)
    not_supported_layers = [l for l in net.layers.keys() if l not in supported_layers]
    if len(not_supported_layers) != 0:
        log.error("Following layers are not supported by the plugin for specified device {}:\n {}".
                  format(plugin.device, ', '.join(not_supported_layers)))
        log.error("Please try to specify cpu extensions library path in demo's command line parameters using -l "
                  "or --cpu_extension command line argument")
        sys.exit(1)
assert len(net.inputs.keys()) == 1, "Demo supports only single input topologies"
assert len(net.outputs) == 1, "Demo supports only single output topologies"
input_blob = next(iter(net.inputs))
out_blob = next(iter(net.outputs))

n, c, h, w = net.inputs[input_blob].shape

log.info("Loading IR to the plugin...")
exec_net = plugin.load(network=net) # <== stuck at this line
```

The only reason I could think of why `ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29` works and `ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03` not is the size which is 33MB for the former and about 100MB for the latter. I think the SSD Resnet50 model may have reached my laptop resource limitation. If this is the cause, how can I get around it? I'm using `l_openvino_toolkit_p_2018.5.455` on Ubuntu 18.04.

The `SSD ResNet50 FPN COCO` model is from TensorFlow Object Detection Models Zoo and supported by Openvino toolkit (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Using-TensorFlow).

Comment: Could you please specify the NCSDK version you're using so that the question stays relevant over time ? You can find that in a file called `version.txt`, my path is `/opt/movidius/version.txt` (for example, my version is `2.10.01.01`).

Answer (score 0):

This model is currently not supported on MYRIAD, this issue is known by the development team. We will keep you update when we will support it.